# Join two maps in hazelcast

Tags: java, hazelcast

I'm using Hazelcast IMDG in my application.

so I have two IMap instances a1 and a2.

```
IMap<Integer, School> a1 = hazelCast.getMap("a1");
                  //school_id, student_id,   highest marks
a1.put(i,new School("1",        "101",       "99.99"));

IMap<Integer, Student> a1 = hazelCast.getMap("a2"); 
                     //id ,  name,   addr           
a2.put(i,new Student("101","banga","kova"))
```

Query:-

```
select a1.school_id,a1.highest_marks,a2.name
FROM a1
INNER JOIN a2
WHERE a1.student_id=a2.id;
```

So here if I want to perform the joins operations means which is the best way to do that..

Please provide some code snippets examples..

Can I go with Hazelcast IMDG or Hazelcast Jet?

Answer (score 0):

Joining of maps is not allowed in Hazelcast IMDG as that defeats the purpose of having the data stored in distributed form. However, you can join the two IMDG maps using Jet. Here is a blog post that provides good example of joining multiple maps: https://hazelcast.org/blog/projections-joins-partition-awareness/